# Display Overdue tickets in Open tickets view with osTicket (v1.10-rc.3)

Tags: php, osticket

I have a default `SLA` plan set to move open tickets to the Overdue tab if there is no activity within 48 hours. What I am trying to achieve is remove the Overdue tab completly and move all overdue tickets to Open tickets

here is the case for Open tickets

```
case 'open':
    $status='open';
    $queue_name = $queue_name ?: 'open';
    $results_type=__('Open Tickets');
    if (!$cfg->showAnsweredTickets())
        $tickets->filter(array('isanswered'=>0));
    $queue_sort_options = array('priority,updated', 'updated',
        'priority,due', 'due', 'priority,created', 'answered', 'number',
        'hot');
    break;
}
```

here is the case for viewing Overdue tickets

```
case 'overdue':
    $status='open';
    $results_type=__('Overdue Tickets');
    $tickets->filter(array('isoverdue'=>1));
    $queue_sort_options = array('priority,due', 'due', 'priority,updated',
        'updated', 'answered', 'priority,created', 'number', 'hot');
    break;
```

Is there a way I can combine both of these queries to show both Open & Overdue tickets on the same page?